# Problemas com googlecharts

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Boa tarde,

Estou com seguinte problema, quando inicializo meu site ele aparece o gráfico belezinha porém quando clico para ir para página ele da problema e não o mostra.

O site esta programado em ajax, portanto eu troco apenas uma div. o código a seguir encontra-se em umas destas páginas que chamo com ajax.

Está pagina eu chamo de dashboard:

```
 google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Usado', 'Liberado'],
        ['Usado', <?php echo $tamanho->USADO ?>],
        ['Liberado', <?php echo $tamanho->LIBERADO ?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Banco de dados',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Na minha index eu incluo o seguinte diretório web:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Quando abro o console do chrome, sou informado do seguinte erro:

`Uncaught Error: google.charts.load() cannot be called more than once with version 44 or earlier.`

Pesquisando na internet não achei nada concreto, porém verifiquei que é algo relacionado a quantidade de chamadas feitas. Não acreditei por motivos óbvios de não funcionamento das alterações.

Alguém sabe como corrigir o problema ?

Comment: Já tentou colocar a chamada `google.charts.load` na sua página inicial?